# Unix script or parser to delete stop words in a file

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, dataset, stop-words

I am looking for a parser or script to remove stop words from a file.

**This is the sample file:**

```
entities_0_confidence|entities_0_name|entities_0_entity|entities_1_confidence|relation_relation|
-1.1956528741743269|ellen brown|Ellen_Brown|-3.9166730593775214|WOULD ATTORNEY FROM|||||||||||||||||||||
-2.3889038197374015|rick santorum|Rick_Santorum||CRITICIZED|||||||||||||||||||||
-1.5485422793287602|thomas jefferson|Thomas_Jefferson|-1.7299349891097682||IS LETTER TO|||||||||||||||||||||
-1.229126527004769|lewis powell|Lewis_Powell_%28conspirator%29|-3.024385187632112|IS JUSTICE OF|||||||||||||||||||||
-2.2268355006701155|michael bloomberg|Michael_Bloomberg|-2.1242762129476493|WON MAYOR OF À|||||||||||||||||||||
```

**This is stop the word list:**

```
IS, OF ,WITH ,WON,WOULD,X,©,® FOR BEST ACTRESS PRESENTING,À,È,ÉS,ŞI,АND,И
```

I just want to remove the words from each line and not the entire line. My current script is removing these words from other words as well.

For example:

- my line in file - "TOLD to stop using this line"
- Stop word - "To"
- Output - "LD  sp using this line"

My file/dataset contains 70k entries.

Comment: You should also show your current script, its output, and what output you'd like to get instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will replace the stop words from beginning/end/in-between the column number passed in the fields variable.

```
fields="col_num=1“ #pass the column you want to remove stop words from

  while word i;
  do 
     str=“word=$i";       
     cat file | 'BEGIN{'$str';'$fields'} {gsub("^'$word'[ ]|[ ]'$word'$|^'$word'$",X,$col_num); gsub("[ ]'$word'[ ]", " ",$col_num); gsub(/^ /,X,$col_num); gsub(/ $/,X,$col_num); print}' > file".temp";
     mv file".temp" file;

  done < stop_words.txt
```

Hope that helps!!